# Setting up email content in editable email notification for Jenkins jobs

Tags: email, jenkins, continuous-integration

I started out by writing html code in the "Default content" section but that is not meeting my requirements since all the information I want to include in the email (html) is not available.

My questions are :

1. How can I set an environment variable in post build actions that I can then use in the default content section ? Is that even possible ?
2. How can I the know the path of a file present in the workspace after the build is done. The path contains a folder that is named using timestamp and I was looking for a way to get to the build results folder for the current build easily. Is there a way ?

Comment: Have you tried 'Editable email notifications' ? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `${ENV, var="VARNAME"}` (where `VARNAME` is the environment variable that you want to reference) anywhere in your HTML

As for your build folder, if it's a random timestamp during the build, you can't reference it unless you save that value to a properties file and then read it with `${PROPFILE,file="FILENAME",property="PROPERTYNAME"}`

If you are using Jenkins's build timestamp `BUILD_ID` then you can reference that as any other environment variable.